# Gradle: Do not let transitive dependencies to be used in project sources

Tags: java, gradle, transitive-dependency

In a project using Java 8, `joda-time` is a transitive dependency of a project dependency. I want to enforce use of `java time` instead of `joda-time` in project source. How can `joda-time` classes be restricted to be used in project source in a gradle project?

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but it sounds like [Checkstyle `IllegalImports`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) (or `ImportControl`) option should work for this. Gradle does have a [checkstyle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out the way to do this with gradle. But I am using IntelliJ's "**Exclude from Import and Completion**" feature as a workaround. It doesn't completely solves the problem but helps while coding. I hope it was helpful.

[image: Exclude from Import and Completion in IntelliJ]